# A database that easy for a developer to use and deploy?

Tags: c#, database, file, file-io

I have created this **interface** for storing data in a file:

```
interface IFileStore {
   bool Import(string);
   string Export();
}
```

...and a **generic class** that implements that interface:

```
class DBTextFile<T> where T : IFileStore, new ()
{
    public List<T> db = new List<T>();

    public void SaveFile(string filename)
    {
        foreach(T d in db) File.WriteToFile(d.Export(), filename);
    }

    public void RestoreFile(string filename)
    {
        db = new List<T>();
        string buffer;
        while(buffer = File.Read(filename) != null)
        {
            T temp = new T();
            if(temp.Import(buffer)) db.Add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

This approach has been working for me for a while. However, I'm finding that I'm having to manage **too many files**. I think it might be more appropriate to use a **database** where each of my files would become a table in that database.

I would like to use a **database that does not require the user to install any software on the user's system**. (I want to keep things simple for the user.) Basically, I just want a database that is easy for me, the developer, to use and deploy.

Would **MySQL** be a good choice? Or would a different database be a better fit for my needs?

Comment: SQLite (nearly ubiquitous but has limited features), SQL Server Compact (Microsofts offering in this market), and Firebird (very feature-rich) are three such (but not the only) options in the no-install/embedded RDBMS market. I would not use Access as a database unless *also using* Access for the other features/environment it offers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different **one file databases**.

The one I'm using and am happy with is : [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

You could also use `access` as Monika suggested, or browse google and see what else you can find ...